# CSS: when img1:hover - img2 hidden and vice versa

Tags: html, css

I have two images encoded in `XSL`. The output method is `HTML`. I would like to hide the image on which `:hover` is not active.

`XSL`:

```
 <div id="img-col-block">
  <a target="_blank" href="{id(substring(@facs, 2))/graphic[@n='1']/@url}" id="{id(substring(@facs, 2))/graphic[@n='1']/@url}">
   <img src="{id(substring(@facs, 2))/graphic[@n='1']/@url}" id="img-col"/>
  </a>
  <a target="_blank" href="{id(substring(@facs, 2))/graphic[@n='2']/@url}" id="{id(substring(@facs, 2))/graphic[@n='2']/@url}">
   <img src="{id(substring(@facs, 2))/graphic[@n='2']/@url}" id="img-colv"/>
  </a>
 </div>
```

`CSS`:

```
  #img-col {height: 4%; width: 4%; border: 3px solid #fff; border-radius: 8px;  margin:  2px 5px -14px;  -webkit-transition: width 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */ transition: width 1s;}
  #img-colv {height: 4%; width: 4%; border: 2px solid orange; border-radius: 8px;  margin:  4px 0px -12px 8px; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */ transition: width 1s;}
  #img-col:hover, #img-colv:hover {width: 97%; margin-left: 0.1%; margin-bottom: 10px; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */ transition: width 1s;}
```

Example of images displayed in a browser before `:hover`: [image: Images displayed on a browser]
So if `:hover` action is made on image "#img-col" then, image "#img-colv" must be hidden. If `:hover` action is made on image "#img-colv" then, image "#img-col" must be hidden.

I have tried with child selector `>` and `{visibility: hidden}` but it's not working.

In advance, thank you for your kind advice.

Comment: What should be the default state of both images?

Comment: @GautamNaik: if I understand your question, default state of both images are displayed with `height:4%` for each, like in the print screen in my message.

Comment: @A.Meshu: thank you for the useful link, however, I've tried `#img-col:hover ~ #img-colv{visibility: hidden}` following the explanation, but it is not working. What did I make wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#img-col").hover(function(){
        $("#img-colv").css("visibility", "hidden");
        }, function(){
        $("#img-colv").css("visibility", "visible");
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#img-colv").hover(function(){
        $("#img-col").css("visibility", "hidden");
        }, function(){
        $("#img-col").css("visibility", "visible");
    });
});
```

```css
 #img-col {height: 4%; width: 4%; border: 3px solid #fff; border-radius: 8px;  margin:  2px 5px -14px;  -webkit-transition: width 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */ transition: width 1s;}
  #img-colv {height: 4%; width: 4%; border: 2px solid orange; border-radius: 8px;  margin:  4px 0px -12px 8px; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */ transition: width 1s;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="img-col-block">
  <a target="_blank" href="{id(substring(@facs, 2))/graphic[@n='1']/@url}" id="{id(substring(@facs, 2))/graphic[@n='1']/@url}">
   <img src="{id(substring(@facs, 2))/graphic[@n='1']/@url}" id="img-col"/>
  </a>
  <a target="_blank" href="{id(substring(@facs, 2))/graphic[@n='2']/@url}" id="{id(substring(@facs, 2))/graphic[@n='2']/@url}">
   <img src="{id(substring(@facs, 2))/graphic[@n='2']/@url}" id="img-colv"/>
  </a>
 </div>
```

This is an example, it is the jquery you must edit.